# Could not capture image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

> - Device: OnePlus 6
> - Storage: 8GB RAM + 128GB ROM
> - Android Version: 10
> - Oxygen OS Version: OP6_02_BETA_31

I use the below code capture image. The code is perfectly working in almost all devices except for the above-mentioned configuration.

The app is opening the camera, and I could not capture the image. With the default camera app, I was not getting any exception. Once the photo is captured, a tick mark button appears to confirm the image. But that button is not being clickable. So, I used a different camera app to capture the image. It returned "Failed to save photo" error in the camera app. No exceptions are thrown.

And I get this message **"E/ContentProviderNative: onTransact error from {P:7857;U:10456}"** in the console. Please assist me with this issue.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            String appDirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            appDir = new File(appDirPath);
            if (!appDir.exists()) {
                appDir.mkdirs();
            }

            mFileCaptured = new File(appDir, tag + ".jpg");

            mImageCaptureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    mFileCaptured);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", mImageCaptureUri));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        context.startActivityForResult(intent, 10000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        Crashlytics.log(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the implementation from https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics.

Now, it's working for me.

Comment: As of 2022-12-08, the link you provided is not available anymore (404 error).

Comment: @JoeMamaJr. Thanks for letting know. The url has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the file (mFileCaptured) you are creating. You have just created the path of the file but the file does not exist in the file system hence the URI of that file is NULL.

try doing this:-

```
    if (!mFileCaptured.exists()) {
            mFileCaptured.createNewFile();
        }
```

if the above code did not work then try this

```
    private static Uri getSharableImageUri(Context context) {
    File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
    File imagePath = new File(outputDir, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    if (!imagePath.exists()) {
        imagePath.mkdir();
    }
    File tempFile = new File(imagePath, "image.jpg");
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        if (!tempFile.exists()) {
            tempFile.createNewFile();
        }
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", tempFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return uri;
    }
```

And use this method to set the URI

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    try {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

            mImageCaptureUri = getSharableImageUri(context);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", mImageCaptureUri));

        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        context.startActivityForResult(intent, 10000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        Crashlytics.log(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Android 10 you cannot write to external storage anymore.

Use getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDirs() instead.

Or request the mediastore for a valid uri to let the camera app write the picture to.